# How can include component js after templete js

Tags: joomla

I added javascript on templete index.php

```
$doc    =   JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/jquery.js', 'text/javascript');
```

and added another on component below

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();      
$document->addScript($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/validation.js');
```

but always js (validation.js) of component getting add before tempelete js(jquery.js)

How can i add component js(validation.js) after templete js(jquery.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `jquery.js` as main jQuery library on your project then you can simple include the `jquery.js` before the head module in `index.php`. like below.

```
<script src="templates/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

Then in your component you can simply use same as below.

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();      
$document->addScript($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/validation.js');
```

An alternate option is Addcustom tag , helps to adding scripts to the document.

```
$document   =   JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag('<script src="'.$this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
```

Otherwise you have to load the component `js` also in `index.php` with second order but that will load the `js` file for all pages.

Hope its helps..

Answer (score 1):

I am going through google and found one solution that i can use custom tag function for component like below:

```
$document   =   JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag('<script src="'.$this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
```

and for template as it below:

```
$doc    =   JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/jquery.js', 'text/javascript')
```

Comment: Nice..yes you can use this method too, if the script file have only limited lines you can use addScriptDeclaration check this too http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript