# Insert javascript before </head> per article/page in Joomla 3.x

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I want to insert Javascript before `</head>` per article/page in Joomla 3.x

I have had a little success using the direct php plugin for joomla using this code in an article:

```
<?php
JHtml::script(Juri::base() . 'files/js/jquery.this-min.js');
?>
```

However it inserts the script tag at the start of the script tags. I want to insert it just before the `</head>` So that it comes after jquery.

For a temporary solution I have included it site wide and this allowed it to be placed just before `</head>` and now the script works properly.

Has anyone had success in doing this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012877/how-can-include-component-js-after-templete-js/21013149#21013149

Comment: Thanks @JobinJose $doc->addCustomTag did the trick! It inserted them below the script tags, yay!  
`$doc = JFactory::getDocument();  
$doc->addCustomTag( '<script src="js/script.js"></script>' );`

Answer (score 1):

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript(JURI::base().'files/js/jquery.this-min.js');
```

That should do it. If you are using Joomla 3 you could consider using the jQuery provided by them, using `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`.

See: http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Javascript_Frameworks for more info on that.

Comment: That works as well but I still have the same problem in that it is inserted at the top of the script tags when I need it at the bottom.
This is also the case when I am adding css files as well.

Comment: Note that the scripts and css files added via addScript and addStyleSheet are added in the head using `<jdoc:include type="head" />` in the template index.php, perhaps that solves your issue ?

Comment: Also: the order of the addScript calls determines the order in which they are added, so if you include a JS that depends on another JS make sure to call that first, so first call `JHTML::_('jquery.framework')` and then `$doc->addScript(...)`.

Comment: I had a problem because my scripts started before jquery in head. That line with jquery.framework helped me a lot! Thanks!